# Gradle file system. Use '/' or File.separator?

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

In regards to Gradle / Groovy , is there any reason I should avoid using '/' instead of File.separator?

As Far as I Know, this was no longer an issue as of Java 7. ...excepting UI displays. Can't seem to find any comments regarding this so I think the answer is 'no' but I've sometimes found that the answer turns out to be, "Yes".

However,  asking anyway.  thanks

Comment: I always use `/` with anything java...  `\\` is for regular expressions and errr...  that's all I think ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use `/` and it works fine.

Even in the [Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileTreeElement.html#getPath()), they don't bother so I'd imagine it's reasonably safe.